# Space character before .toFixed method

Tags: javascript, numbers, tofixed

I noticed that if you put a space character before `.toFixed` method, it will work without errors. I understand why it's work with a parenthesis `(2).toFixed(2)`, but why does it work with space?

```js
console.log(2 .toFixed(2))
// 2.00
```

```js
console.log(2.toFixed(2))
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Please leave links to any information about this. Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(2..toFixed(2))` , first one act as decimal point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the usual whitespace before the (dot) operator.

Maybe you have a look here, too: [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation)

```js
console.log(2 .toFixed(2))
```